# How to make a cookie, that is random, and won't change once the user comes back (can't be PHPSESSID= because im running node.js)

Tags: javascript, php, web

I'm trying to create a cookie that acts like a PHPSESSID but is JavaScript, I would just use PHP but i'm running node so that is impossible. The hope is that you get a 7 long character id that stays even when you reload the page and can't be replicated. This is what I have tryed but it creates a new one instead of keeping it every time.

```js
 function randomString() {  
            //define a variable consisting alphabets in small and capital letter  
    var characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";  
              
            //specify the length for the new string  
    var lenString = 7;  
    var randomstring = '';  
  
            //loop to select a new character in each iteration  
    for (var i=0; i<lenString; i++) {  
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length);  
        randomstring += characters.substring(rnum, rnum+1);  
    }  
  var thing = randomstring;
    document.cookie = `${thing};expires=4000;`
}
```

Comment: Well if you don't check for the existence of a cookie before running `randomString()`, for sure it will be recreated on each page load. You also don't name the cookie, you just assign a value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I just tryed the `domain=https://example.com/;` and that worked, maybe theres a better way feel free to post other answers! fullcode,

```js
  function randomString() {  
            //define a variable consisting alphabets in small and capital letter  
    var characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";  
              
            //specify the length for the new string  
    var lenString = 7;  
    var randomstring = '';  
  
            //loop to select a new character in each iteration  
    for (var i=0; i<lenString; i++) {  
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length);  
        randomstring += characters.substring(rnum, rnum+1);  
    }  
  var thing = randomstring;
    document.cookie = `${thing};expires=4000;domain=https://eez.penguinpowers.repl.co;`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

express-session, It's basically PHPSessionID but for Express.js
([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session))

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Try to explain a bit more your answer and why it might solve the OP question. Try to avoid just adding a link to the useful information, since the linked page might disappear in the future.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).